# How do I configure the entries that appear in the BURG menu?

Tags: dual-boot, burg

I am experimenting with BURG to make the boot menu look a bit nicer (I am dual booting W7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).  I managed to install BURG and selected my chosen theme, but I can't find a way to remove or rename entries on the menu! I have about 4 or 5 different ones, but all I want to see is Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7.

How do I do this?  I have tried Super Boot Manager, I have tried editing the Burg files, but I cannot figure out how to do this.  This is one of the things that I find irritating as someone who is trying to learn Ubuntu - Nothing is ever simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

And install grub-customizer:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

It's a GUI to manage both, grub and burg.

Comment: I have Grub Customizer, but as far as I can see, it isn't working with BURG :-(

Comment: It should detect burg if it's properly installed... Try to run "sudo update-grub && sudo update-burg" in a terminal.